# How to communicate using IP address between two android phones?

Tags: android, tcp, communication

It is possible to query two android phone’s IP address respectively. It is 3g link.

Is it possible to do tcp communication use this IP address directly?

Hope someone can give me some advice! Thanks.

Comment: probably not, as most carriers NAT your device on their network (making it not directly accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If addresses is known maybe you can use [sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) to communicate between phones.

Also you can use some host as server which coordinates clients.